# Regex for string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have string on C#: 
`string buf = "\r\n    \r\n        \r\n            103E\r\n        \r\n    \r\n    \r\n        \r\n            \r\ntest1            \r\n        \r\n        \r\n                test2\r\n        \r\n    \r\n    \r\n        \r\n            \r\n        \r\n    \r\n    \r\n        &nbsp;x16\r\n    \r\n"`

I want to get the strings

```
1. 103E
2. test1
3. test2
4. 16
```

How to do it using regex.

Comment: What makes the 'x' in x16 invalid?

Comment: @Henk Holterman agreed, more explanation is needed before anything better than my answer is possible

Comment: are you sure you need regex? it is a costly operation in simple scenarios like this, consider regular string replacement

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu: You've got it backwards.  In a simple scenario like this, the relative cost of regexes is utterly insignificant.  And in *any* scenario, to reject regexes on the basis of performance *without even trying them* is premature optimization, pure and simple.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var separator = new string[] { "\r", "\n", " ", "&nbsp;" };
var result = buf.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// result == { "103E", "test1", "test2", "x16" }
```

Note that, if your input is arbitrary HTML, you should use an HTML parser.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: I would bet that question's author was wrong regarding "16", hope he will clarify this point soon

Answer (score 0):

`\S+` will match one or more non-whitespace characters. That should get you started.

source: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: @Henk "That should get you started."